# Recording time using Xcode?

Tags: xcode, time

Is it possible to somehow record the time you are spending using Xcode?
Somekind of application that sets off a stopwatch when Xcode is the main window while the screensaver is not running?

Just wondering how I can do time management more automated, so I don't have to start a timer each time I start to work and count up afterwards...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a plugin called "Wakatime", which may do what you are asking: https://github.com/wakatime/xcode-wakatime

Haven't tried it myself though

Comment: Will try this out tomorrow, looks great! Doesn't mention compatibility with Xcode6 though.